# psql SHELL stuck in -- More -- after selecting * from table

Tags: postgresql, shell, terminal, psql, pager

I am here with a friend learning PostgreSQL and we are creating some tables. When he runs SELECT * FROM person (our table name) from his mac terminal and when I run it from the psql Shell, we are actually stuck in the terminal before all of the data are displayed.

I used Mackaroo to generate some random data, 500 names in total and this the problem is displayed in the following picture: Instead of terminating the terminals is it possible to display all of the data immediately instead of pressing enter for every line? Or just be able to type the next command?

[image: sql shell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the pager in `psql` with `\pset pager 0`.

Comment: Thanks Mureinik! It's fixed. I appreciate it :)